# Comparing Sheetnames of different excel workbooks and Storing the result in the third sheet

Tags: excel, macros, excel-formula, vba

There is a folder in which we have three excel workbooks:-

1. setA(which has n number of sheets)
2. SetB(which has n number of sheets)
3. Difference

I want to have a button in "Difference" ,clicking on which will compare the sheet names of SetA to that of SetB and store the result is Difference.

Example:- 
I actually need to compare the data to the 2 workbooks(i.e SetA and SetB) . But this comparison has to be there sheet wise like if SetA has 2 sheet named "India" and "America" and setB has 2 sheets named "India" and "Football" then my macro should compare the name of the sheet first and if it matches then only it should compare its data.     So the data comparison of "India" should happen and "Football" should not happen.

I need to submit it tonight and I am from pure DB background.

I am totally new to excel can you please guide how to acheive it?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials online for this kind of thing. This is not the place to seek guidance or tutoring. We provide specific answers to specific questions

Comment: Thanks for the comment. but i need to give it by today,so wont be having time for tutorial

Comment: So, basically, you want a list of __unique__ worksheet names (a list of names that are not in both workbooks)? What is this for?

Comment: No, I want to compare the names of the sheets in both the excel workbooks i.e SetA and SetB

Comment: @SouraviSinha Can you, at least, give an example of the expected output? And what is this for?

Comment: Sure, I actually need to compare the data to the 2 workbooks(i.e SetA and SetB) . But this comparison has to be there sheet wise like if SetA has 2 sheet named "India" and "America" and setB has 2 sheets named "India" and "Football" then my macro should compare the name of the sheet first and if it matches then only it should compare its data.     So the data comparison of "India" should happen and "Football" should not happen.

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't a homework service, but if you give it a go and edit in the issues that you face / errors you are seeing then people will be more inclined to help you out and suggest better methodologies

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor    I am sorry,if my question has voilated the aim of this forum,after doing a lot of searches I thought this forum could guide me as i tried recording Macros,doing hit and trial VBA programming but couldnt get lucky..Hence i turned to this forum for help.If it is not possible here then its ok...I will find out a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this will do what you want.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FileListingAllFolder()

Dim pPath As String
Dim FlNm As Variant
Dim ListFNm As New Collection ' create a collection of filenames

Dim OWb As Workbook
Dim ShtCnt As Integer
Dim Sht As Integer

Dim MWb As Workbook
Dim MWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

' Open folder selection
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    pPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Create master workbook with single sheets
Set MWb = Workbooks.Add(1)
MWb.Sheets(1).Name = "Result"
Set MWs = MWb.Sheets("Result")
Cells(1, 1) = "No."
Cells(1, 2) = "Sheet Name"
Cells(1, 3) = "File Name"
Cells(1, 4) = "Link"
i = 2

' Filling a collection of filenames (search Excel files including subdirectories)
Call FlSrch(ListFNm, pPath, "*.xls", True)

' Print list to immediate debug window and as a message window
For Each FlNm In ListFNm ' cycle for list(collection) processing

    'Start Processing here
    Set OWb = Workbooks.Open(FlNm)
    ShtCnt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For Sht = 1 To ShtCnt
        MWs.Cells(i, 1) = i - 1
        MWs.Cells(i, 2) = Sheets(Sht).Name
        MWs.Cells(i, 3) = OWb.Name
        MWs.Cells(i, 4).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FlNm & """,""Click Here"")"
        i = i + 1
    Next Sht
    'End file processing file
    OWb.Close False
Next FlNm

' Print to immediate debug window and message if no file was found
If ListFNm.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No file was found !"
    MsgBox "No file was found !"
    MWb.Close False
    End
End If

MWb.Activate
MWs.Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

End

NextCode:
MsgBox "You Click Cancel, and no folder selected!"

End Sub

Private Sub FlSrch(pFnd As Collection, pPath As String, pMask As String, pSbDir As Boolean)

Dim flDir As String
Dim CldItm As Variant
Dim sCldItm As New Collection

' Add backslash at the end of path if not present
pPath = Trim(pPath)
If Right(pPath, 1) <> "\" Then pPath = pPath & "\"

' Searching files accordant with mask
flDir = Dir(pPath & pMask)
    Do While flDir <> ""
        pFnd.Add pPath & flDir 'add file name to list(collection)
        flDir = Dir ' next file
    Loop

' Procedure exiting if searching in subdirectories isn't enabled
If Not pSbDir Then Exit Sub

' Searching for subdirectories in path
flDir = Dir(pPath & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While flDir <> ""

        ' Add subdirectory to local list(collection) of subdirectories in path
        If flDir <> "." And flDir <> ".." Then If ((GetAttr(pPath & flDir) And _
        vbDirectory) = 16) Then sCldItm.Add pPath & flDir
        flDir = Dir 'next file
    Loop

' Subdirectories list(collection) processing
For Each CldItm In sCldItm
    Call FlSrch(pFnd, CStr(CldItm), pMask, pSbDir) ' Recursive procedure call
Next

End Sub
```